# distance vector routing using bellmann ford algorithm for a cost matrix of an undirected graph

Tags: c++, shortest-path, bellman-ford

I am trying to implement distance vector algorithm using bellman ford algorithm for an directed graph . My input is the initial matrix which describes the weight of the nodes adjacent to other nodes. In order to calculate shortest path between nodes , I also need to calculate the iterations that will occur of the changes in the matrix . How to calculate the iterations after which the matrix will give shortest path for all the nodes? 
sample initial matrix of nodes is as below , we are considering the graph as

```
R1 -> R2 = 3
R1 -> R3 = 999
R1 -> R4 = 7
R2 -> R3 = 6
R2 -> R4 = 999
R3 -> R4 = 2
```

Here 999 is considered as infinity as the nodes are not directly connected.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: ...and what does it have to do with C++?

Comment: I am trying to implement this in c++ and my question is how to calculate the number of iterations to the initial matrix after which it will generate the matrix containing the shortest distance

Answer (score 0):

This seems like something you should be able to derive from [the algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm). AFAICS, the matrix will be filled with the result after basically [image: |V|*|E|] iterations.